# Running upset()，Error in colSums(temp_data) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

I'm studying someone else's runtime code and I'm getting an error, how do I fix it?

```
library(UpSetR)

otu <- read.delim('otu_table.txt', header = TRUE, row.names = 1, sep = '\t')
otu1 <- otu
otu1[otu1 > 0] <- 1
upset(otu1)
```

> Appears     Error in colSums(temp_data) : 'x' must be numeric

'otu_table.txt' reads

OTU_ID  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  taxonomy
OTU_2   0.001857717 0.001126812 0.002527713 0.001705445 0.001370447 0.001888172 Actinobacteria
OTU_3   0.000395907 9.13631E-05 0.000152272 0.000152272 0.000395907 0.000334998 Proteobacteria
OTU_4   3.04544E-05 0.000456816 0.000121818 0.001065903 0.000182726 0.000182726 Proteobacteria

```
sapply (otu1, class)

c1          c2          c3          c4          c5"numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"c6    taxonomy"numeric" "character"

> otu1 <- as.numeric(otu1)

Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Column taxonomy "character" change also does not work, thank you for your reply.